# The node to be removed is not a child of this node JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, removechild

Other stack answers have failed to fix my problem because I think this occurs for different reasons. My JS code:

```
const addButton = document.querySelector('.addButton')
var input = document.querySelector('.input')
const draggable_list = document.getElementById('draggable-list'); //draggable_list is a ul

let itemBox;
let items;
const array = [];
const listItems = [];
let dragStartIndex;

class item {
    constructor(itemName) {
        this.createDiv(itemName);
    }

    createDiv(itemName) {    
        let removeButton = document.createElement('button');
        removeButton.innerHTML = 'REMOVE';
        removeButton.classList.add('removeButton');

        draggable_list.appendChild(items);
        items.appendChild(removeButton);

        removeButton.addEventListener('click', () => this.remove(items);
    }
    async remove(item, value) {
        draggable_list.removeChild(item) 
    }
}

async function check() {
    if (input.value != '') {
        array.push(input.value)
        listItems.push(input.value) 
        array.forEach((numbers,index) => {
            items = document.createElement('li')
            items.setAttribute('data-index', index)
            items.innerHTML = `
            <div class="draggable" draggable="true">
                <p class="phone-number">${numbers}</p>
                <i class="fas fa-grip-lines"></i>
            </div>`;

        } )
        new item(input.value)
        input.value = ''
}

addButton.addEventListener('click', check)
```

When `remove()` is called for the first time, it successfully removes the **last** `li` element. But when it is called again, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Node.removeChild: The node to be removed is not a child of this node
```

Comment: Why are those functions async?

Comment: I used this code from an open source code. I don't know why exactly but without them nothing works

Comment: They need not have to be an `async`.

Comment: This code needs to be completely rewritten as it's following lots of bad habits.  Putting `items` in a global, then overwriting it, then expecting to use it multiple times later is just wrong and probably related to your problem, but honestly the code is so convoluted that I can't really tell what it's supposed to do.

Comment: It looks like you want to use this code in a browser, so [node.js] seems to be a wrong tag here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you...

```js
const addButton = document.querySelector('.addButton');
const input = document.querySelector('.input');
const draggable_list = document.getElementById('draggable-list');
//draggable_list is a ul

let itemBox;
let items;
const array = [];
const listItems = [];
let dragStartIndex;

class Item {
  constructor(itemName) {
    this.createDiv(itemName);
  }
  createDiv(itemName) {
    let input = document.createElement('input');
    input.value = itemName;

    let removeButton = document.createElement('button');
    removeButton.innerHTML = 'REMOVE'
    removeButton.classList.add('removeButton');

    draggable_list.appendChild(items);
    items.appendChild(removeButton);

    removeButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

      if (event && event.target.parentElement) {
        // this.remove(items));
        this.remove(event.target.parentElement);
      }
    });
  }
  remove(item, value) {
    draggable_list.removeChild(item);
  }
}

function check() {
  if (input.value != '') {
    array.push(input.value);
    listItems.push(input.value);
    array.forEach((numbers, index) => {
      items = document.createElement('li');
      items.setAttribute('data-index', index)
      items.innerHTML = `
            <div class="draggable" draggable="true">
                <p class="phone-number">${numbers}</p>
                <i class="fas fa-grip-lines"></i>
            </div>`;

    });
    new Item(input.value);
    input.value = '';
  }
}

addButton.addEventListener('click', check)
```

```html
<button class="addButton">+</button>
<input type="text" class="input" />

<ul id="draggable-list">

</ul>
```

Comment: I don't know how to thank you... This worked!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying and pasting some convoluted code you don't understand you should try and write it yourself. Try and focus on what you require and nothing else.

Here is one way of doing it:

```js
const [inp,btn,ul]=["input","button","ul"].map(e=>document.querySelector(e));

btn.onclick=function(){
 ul.innerHTML+=`<li><p>${inp.value}</p><button>delete</button></li>`;
 inp.value="";
}

ul.onclick=function(ev){
  if (ev.target.tagName==="BUTTON")
    ul.removeChild(ev.target.closest("li"));
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button>add</button>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works well. You are right about writing the code myself but I am still learning so I found an online code and tried to understand it and modify it.